# How do I parse multiple matches using jq?

Tags: json, jq

How do I get the first index of a query that contains multiple matches? I am trying to get the value of the first key called **ELEMENT** in this query:

````
```
{
  "ELEMENT": "FADC6B14-0369-4FF4-9ADC-A5E0F5C6D30D",
  "type": "XCUIElementTypeStaticText",
  "label": "this.com"
}
{
  "ELEMENT": "CC89DD73-AB90-495E-A90B-74722C56DD46",
  "type": "XCUIElementTypeStaticText",
  "label": "this.com"
}
{
  "ELEMENT": "B888ADA6-4209-44C4-BCB8-F5174312D102",
  "type": "XCUIElementTypeStaticText",
  "label": "this.com"
}
{
  "ELEMENT": "9A6E77C7-E93D-41DE-9163-2CB60B8DD2FB",
  "type": "XCUIElementTypeStaticText",
  "label": "this.com"
}
```
````

Here is the cURL that produces this result:

```
curl -X POST $JSON_HEADER -d "{\"using\":\"partial link text\",\"value\":\"label=this.com\"}" $DEVICE_URL/session/$SESSION_ID/elements | jq -r '.value[] | select(.label=="this.com")'
```

I was thinking it could be `label[0]=="this.com"` but I get the message **Cannot index string with number**

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using single quotes `'{"using": "partial link test", "value": "label=this.com"}'` or `"$(jq -n '{using: "partial link test", value: "label=this.com"}')"` to create the JSON for the `-d` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like .value contains an array; if so, then the jq query that matches your description would be:

```
.value | map( select(.label=="this.com")) | .[0]
```

If there is no match, this will produce `null`, so you might want to make adjustments accordingly.

If you want the value of .ELEMENT in the first match, you could consider:

```
.value | map( select(.label=="this.com")) | .[0] // empty | .ELEMENT
```

If your jq has `first/1`, a more efficient solution is possible:

```
first( .value[] | select(.label=="this.com") ) | . ELEMENT
```

Comment: Thank you @peak! the latter part of your answer resolved the problem. The only thing that is still not clear to me is the escaping with the keyword "empty" after the index .[0] in your answer. I looked on https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x) and that didn't bring any clarity.